# Japanese/Korean characters encoding issue on IIS7 windows 2008 server

Tags: iis, encoding, utf-8

I have just transferred a site from iss on a windows 2003 to a 2008 server.

Everything is working as before, except some pages in Japanese and Korean, where the text comes out like a garbled mess:

‰‹ã®ãƒ‡ã‚¤ãƒ ãƒ»ã‚¸ãƒ§ãƒ¼ãƒ³ãƒ»ã‚µã‚¶ãƒ¼ãƒ©ãƒ³ãƒ‰ã€ã‚µãƒ¼ãƒ»ãƒˆãƒ¼ãƒžã‚¹ãƒ»ã‚¢ãƒ¬ãƒ³ã€ã‚¢ãƒ«ãƒ•ã‚£ãƒ¼ãƒ»ãƒœãƒ¼ã‚„æ¥½å™¨æ¼”å¥å®¶ã‚¸ã‚§ãƒ¼ãƒ ã‚ºãƒ»ã‚´ãƒ¼ãƒ«ã‚¦ã‚§ã‚¤ã€ã‚¸ãƒ§ãƒ³ãƒ»ãƒªãƒ«ã€ãƒŠã‚¿ãƒªãƒ¼ãƒ»ã‚¯ãƒ©ã‚¤ãƒ³ã¨ã„ã£ãŸé¡”ã¶ã‚Œã§ã™ã€‚

It looks like this.

The character encoding is set to UTF-8 as it was before.  Is there a server setting that needs to be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out why this was happening - even though the meta tag set the page to be encoded in utf-8.  An incorrect setting in IIS caused the mangling of the Japanese and Korean characters.

I fixed this in the following way:

1. Went to IIS Manager
2. Went to .NET Globalization settings
3. Made sure that the File encoding was set to utf-8

Then everything started working as expected.