# Email characters show as weird characters when project published in MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

When I publish my project to host Email characters show as weird characters. Attached photo shows my problem.

[image]

@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)

In localhost Email characters do not have any problem.

Comment: '@Html.DisplayNameFor' will display the label of the value. I think you have some problem in your @Html.DisplayFor helper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with server encoding configurations on which your site is being hosted try change encoding but keep in mind it could change the language you are using in your application

**Read Here**

https://serverfault.com/questions/80895/how-do-i-change-the-default-character-encoding-in-iis-on-windows-server-2003

**Use This Inside webconfig**

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
  <globalization 
     requestEncoding="iso-8859-1"
     responseEncoding="iso-8859-1"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

or as mentioned [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334728/japanese-korean-characters-encoding-issue-on-iis7-windows-2008-server)

**Made sure that the File encoding was set to utf-8**

Please ask your server administrator to make changes on server configurations.